# How do I use ColorFilter with React-Native-Lottie?

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie, bodymovin

I cannot seem to get the colorFilter prop working with my .json file.
There are no errors but the colours are clearly not changing.

```
<LottieView
     style={{
         width: 90,
         height: 90,
     }}
     colorFilters={
       [
         {
         keypath: "asdf",
         color: "#abcdef",
         }
       ]
     }
     source={badge.icon}
     loop={false}
/>
```

I'm importing the .json from After Effects using BodyMovin
but am I changing the layer name correctly? If not why on earth is this not working?
[image]

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, still nothing

Comment: I've found a workaround, now I post it, hope that help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't get colorFilters to work but you can try doing the following:

```
import myAnimation from "./../img/myAnimation.json";
```

in the render part use LottieView with the import and not with the require inline

```
<LottieView        
  //source={require("./../img/radius.json")}
  source={myAnimation}
/>
```

Now you can manipulate the properties directly from the json object, just for example here I manipulate the color based on the actual color (from black to white or from white to black)

```
myAnimation.layers[1].shapes[0].it[1].c.k = myAnimation.layers[1].shapes[0].it[1].c.k[0] == 0 ?  [1,1,1,1] : [0,0,0,1];
```

To find out what is the property you need, check the json, it is not very clear but with some trial and error you can understand the structure.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I guess this would work. Shame there's no easier way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is the way. So I made a tool to help - https://colorize-react-native-lottie.netlify.app/

Comment: @Noitidart this is best thing I have seen so far (considering how weird are the names of the layers sometimes)! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

Just try with react native, and it's work fine for me

```
    <LottieView
                style={style.heartLootie}
                source={require("../../assets/animations/favorite_animation.json")}
                progress={animationProgress}
                colorFilters={[
                    { keypath: "Red Heart", color: themeColors.PRIMARY },
                    { keypath: "Grey Heart", color: themeColors.SECONDARY },
                ]}
            />
```

Comment: How can I find the key path? should I look into the Lottie json file? is it a namespace of the color or the layers?

Comment: Aha I've got it, in the json file there's a layer array which inside it you can see a property name "nm", so we can change the layer's color by their name.

Answer (score 2):

This is an outstanding issue, I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/issues/671) and will work with the devs to hopefully resolve this issue. It is probably the biggest bottleneck for React Native adoption right now.