# Change lottie fill colour react native

Tags: react-native, lottie

I want to change the fill colour on a single element in a lottie.json file conditionally. How can I access the fill of 'circle' and update the colour?

I currently have this

```
<LottieView
          source={require('../assets/splash_logo_2.json')}
          autoPlay
          loop={false}
          onAnimationFinish={() => {
            progress.value = 1;
          }}
          colorFilters={[
            {
              keypath: 'circle',
              color: progress.value === 1 ? '#85AA82' : '#B5FFAF',
            },
          ]}
        />
```

Comment: does the animation json have a layer called circle? if you are not sure you can import you animation to https://lottiefiles.com/editor, and check the layer names on the left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this answer:

[How do I use ColorFilter with React-Native-Lottie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500619/how-do-i-use-colorfilter-with-react-native-lottie)

and also this tool to help you to identify it better:

https://colorize-react-native-lottie.netlify.app/